# Opacity influencing the z-index with floats

Tags: html, css, css-float, opacity

After trying to figure out what's wrong with my floated images, I noticed that opacity seems to have a strange bug:

http://jsfiddle.net/tshwbnLo/

If you have an element with opacity, it just draws "over" the floated image, instead of going with the expected behaviour. Since I used headers that have a `border-bottom` those borders were always drawn **over** the floating image.

<strike>Using `positon: relative` to set the `z-index` manually isn't going to work, since I still need the floating image to behave like one</strike>

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found so far (if other people run into this) is to use RGBA colors instead of setting an overall opacity, i.e:

```
color: rgba(?, ?, ?, opacity)
border-color: rgba(?, ?, ?, opacity)
background-color: rgba(?, ?, ?, opacity)
```

But is there an easier / cleaner way? It seems more like a dirty hack than a real solution, just to achieve exactly the same result! (except for the weird z-index).

**Edit:** I was wrong, `position: relative; z-index: 2` actually works even with `float`. I'm still curious about better solutions though, I think this should just work out of the box after all.